# How to change background color of div

Tags: jquery, css

How shall  change background color for below css using jquery

When tried using this it show me error of undefined

```
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName('Title');
            element.style.background = '#FF00AA';
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
> 'background')

```
.orgchart .node .title {
    position: relative!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    font-weight: bold!important;
    height: 20px!important;
    line-height: 20px!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis!important;
    white-space: nowrap!important;
    background-color: #eb3c96!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0!important;
    font-family: Calibri !important;
    width: 185px!important;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the script is run after the DOM is ready, move it to the bottom of you document and try again.

Comment: you have an uppercase T in "Title". just use `document.querySelector('.title').style.backgroundColor = '#fff';`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using backgroundColor - see example link

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **document.getElementsByClassName** returns an *array-like HTMLCollection object*.
You should access an element of this collection to set the element's style properties, otherwise you get an **undefined** value, as described in the mozilla docs in the [4th example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#:%7E:text=document.getElementsByClassName(%27test%27)%5B0%5D).

Second, the **background** is a shorthand for a handful of other properties, if you only change the background color of an element, you should probably use the more specific **backgroundColor** property, like the comment mentioned.

I have written a small script, which sets the background color of the first (and only) element using the class name. You can run it to view the results.

More info on **document.getElementsByClassName** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and on **style.background** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

```js
// access the first element of the array with [0]
const divToChange = document.getElementsByClassName('Title')[0];

// use the more specific 'backgroundColor' property if possible
divToChange.style.backgroundColor = "#FF00AA";
```

```html
<h3 class="Title">Change my background</h3>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a live NodeList, not an Array.